# Using Java Streams for Efficient Search

Tags: performance, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of elements that have no measurable order among them. Their attributes are also complex enough that I cannot simply insert them into a `Set` (since different attributes may represent the same element).

Through the course of my program, I analyse each element in the list and, based on it, other elements are added (like building a graph and going to each node to add additional paths and nodes). However, they added elements may be equivalent to other elements in the `List`. In this case they are not added, and the equivalent element has a property changed (let's assume, a counter).

I've been using this code to find whether an equivalent state exists:

```
public static State stateAlreadyExists(State current) {
    for (State any : list) {
        if (equivalencyMethod(any, current)) {
            return any;
        }
     }
     return null;
}
```

However, this code, albeit having `O(n)` complexity, is not performant enough for my case. Every element I add will have this code executed, and I add about `sqrt(N)` elements per analysed element (so, analysing the element 400 is creating 20 new elements, for example). To increase the performance, I used Java's parallel streams:

```
public static State stateAlreadyExists(State current) {
    Optional<State> opt = list.parallelStream().filter(
        any -> equivalencyMethod(any, current)).findFirst();
    if (opt.isPresent()) {
        return opt.get();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the performance increased significantly. <strike>The problem is this code isn't really equivalent, since we analyse the entire stream before returning an element. Most times, the equivalent element is in the first `sqrt(N)` elements of the list, so a method that stops on the first match would be better.</strike>

I'm aware there is a `noneFound()` method for [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). It returns as soon as a match is found. However, it returns a `boolean`, not the element itself. Is there a way to use this or a similarly built method to return the first match found?

According to the JavaDoc, findFirst():

> returns the first element of this stream

While findAny():

> selects any element in the stream. This is to allow for maximal performance in parallel operations.

So, my code can become even more performant by using the `findAny()` call, since order doesn't really matter for my problem, due to there being only 1 equivalent element at any time.

Comment: `findFirst()` returns as soon as a match is found (unless your stream is ordered), so the entire stream isn't analyzed unless it is necessary.

Comment: `findFirst()` doesn't take any arguments. It just returns the first element of the stream

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Isn't the first element what you want?

Comment: “since we analyse the entire stream before returning an element”— so your problem is that assumption, out of thin air, despite the fact that you already acknowledged a performance gain?

Comment: I didn't realize `findFirst()` could interrupt the filter operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findFirst` is a short-circuiting terminal operation (thanks [Keppil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343161/keppil)).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final AtomicInteger countNew = new AtomicInteger();
  final AtomicInteger countDoStuff = new AtomicInteger();
  class A {
    A() { countNew.getAndIncrement(); }
    public boolean doStuff() { return countDoStuff.getAndIncrement() % 3 == 2; }
  }
  Stream.generate(A::new).limit(20).filter(A::doStuff).findFirst();
  System.out.println("Number of times an A was created: " + countNew);
  System.out.println("Number of times doStuff was called: " + countDoStuff);
}
```

this code will print

> Number of times an A was created: 3
>
> Number of times doStuff was called: 3

but not

> Number of times an A was created: 20
>
> Number of times doStuff was called: 20

or even less

> Number of times an A was created: 20
>
> Number of times doStuff was called: 3

Comment: It is even a _short-circuiting_ terminal operation, which is why it stops when it finds a match.

Comment: Yeah, but it will search for the entire list (all 20 elements) and then pick the first that matches. It won't return immediately at 3, will it?

Comment: Yes, it will: doStuff is called only 3 times. If it does what you say it does, that means that the findFirst doesn't perform 1 loop, but 2. Which is not the case.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I've adapted my code to show you that 1. only 3 instances of `A` are generated and 2. only 3 calls on `doStuff()` are performed. So there is only 1 loop ever done and the code will not create 20 `A` then only filter them.

Comment: I didn't realize `findFirst()` could interrupt the filter operations. My code is as performant as it can get using parallel stream, then, I assume?

Comment: @BlueMoon93: think about whether you really need the *first* match or any match would suffice. In the latter case, you may use `findAny()` instead of `findFirst()`. This can improve the parallel performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you an alternative approach. Try to formulate your equivalency criteria in a way such that you can create a hash function that substantially reduces the number of pairwise equivalency checks that you have to do. For the hash function it's no problem if two non-equal items have the same hash, the only important is that two equal items have the same hash. Then you can simply store your elements in a `HashSet` which would do the heavy work for you, you would only have to implement `equals(Object other)` and `hashCode()` of the elements.

If finding a proper hash code is impossible, you could still think if you are able to *sort* your objects, that is you can formulate a comparison function that can tell the order of any two of your objects (or that they are equal). Then you could use a `TreeSet` with your custom comparator and that would also work super fast.

Comment: I thought about your suggestions, but they are not applicable in my case. There is no meaningful order that can be used, and the comparison cannot be done through hashes. +1 for the idea though